# Unable to get Stackdriver Trace information in Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-stackdriver

I have a few microservices running in Container Engine (GKE) and I'm trying to get trace information in Google Console, but something goes wrong.

Here is my checklist:

- Stackdriver Trace API is enabled in API Manager.
- API Manager dashboard shows 99.98% error ratio.
- GKE has permissions:

  - Stackdriver Trace: Write Only
  - Stackdriver Logging API: Write Only
  - Stackdriver Monitoring API: Full
  - Service Control: Enabled
- There are no errors in logs
- I used the following manuals to integrate Trace API:

  - [ASP.NET Core](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore/index.html)
  - [Go](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/trace)

Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

[image: api manager errors]

---

Update: I was able to query trace api manually via curl from GKE pod:

```
kubectl exec -it POD -- /bin/bash

curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"


curl --verbose -d '{"traces": [{"projectId":"xxxx","traceId":"12345678901234567890123456789053","spans":[{"spanId":3,"name":"test"}]}]}' -X PATCH https://cloudtrace.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx/traces -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization":"Bearer TOKEN"
```

curl output:

- Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
- Trying 173.194.202.95...
- Connected to cloudtrace.googleapis.com (173.194.202.95) port 443 (#0)
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
- SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
- SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
- Server certificate:
- subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.googleapis.com
- start date: 2017-07-05 08:20:33 GMT
- expire date: 2017-09-27 08:09:00 GMT
- subjectAltName: cloudtrace.googleapis.com matched
- issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
- SSL certificate verify ok.

  > PATCH /v1/projects/line-b/traces HTTP/1.1
  >   User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
  >   Host: cloudtrace.googleapis.com
  >   Accept: */*
  >   Content-Type: application/json
  >   Authorization:Bearer TOKEN
  >   Content-Length: 118
- upload completely sent off: 118 out of 118 bytes
  < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  ...

Dashboard also updated:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your actual code where you are using the Stackdriver Trace API. Also provide your project ID if you are comfortable sharing that, as it will help on my end to see if I can uncover anything. If not, you can open an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to Google and provide the above information.

Comment: @Jordan created issue report - 63444729

Answer (score 4):

You can look directly at the [API reporting graphs](http://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudtrace.googleapis.com/overview) to see that your calls to `google.devtools.cloudtrace.v1.TraceService.PatchTraces` fail with `403 Forbidden` errors.

403 Forbidden is caused when a request to a server is not authorized. Therefore, your calls from your Container Engine (GKE) cluster to 'cloudtrace.PatchTraces' are not authorized.

This could be due to the limited Stackdriver Trace 'Write Only' permission you set. Also, ensure that you added the ['trace.append' scope](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/aspnet#container_engine) when creating the cluster.

---

Concerning the missing logs in Stackdriver. Once Stackdriver Logging is enabled for your cluster you should be able to simply write to 'STDOUT' and 'STDERR'. Fluentd should take care of sending this to Stackdriver and the output should be available in the [Log Viewer](http://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) under the 'GKE Container' dropdown.

Alternatively you can always use the [Stackdriver Logging Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries) to directly write to Stackdriver, just as you are doing with the Stackdriver Trace API. You should also set the [Log Severity](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogSeverity) to make filtering easier in the Log Viewer to find specific error logs (like the 403s you are seeing).

Comment: this is not permission problem, all instances has "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs". Moreover I was able to send PatchTraces manually via curl. As for logging it' set to "Write Only" which should be enough to send logs (I receive logs data from containers).

Comment: How are you authenticating the cURL request? Could you also provide the sample cURL code that is working for you in your original answer.

Comment: yes, see update

Comment: Since you have confirmed that it is indeed working with the Default Service Account, I ask that you triple check that you have properly followed all of the steps for [Setting Up Cloud Trace in C#](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/#vms_or_containers). Check that you have properly configured the Client Library and enabled the access scope. If it still doesn't work, try manually setting the 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' environment variable as described at the bottom on the setup guide.